# How to find Inverse Laplace transform of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^2}\right)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

> How to find Inverse Laplace transform of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^2}\right)$?

---

I don't understand how to rewrite it and use the table of Laplace transforms.

Comment: Maple gives the result:

$2\sinh(t)\sin(t)/t.$

I don't think that this Laplace transform is trivial. You should look this up in a table.

Comment: There is no excuse to be asking such poorly stated questions.  You have supposedly "earned" more than 750 in rep, so you're no "newbie".  I'd advise you to familiarize yourself with the help section (upmost tab to the right), and pay particular attention to "How to ask a good question."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^2}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s+1}\right)$$
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^2}\right)\right](t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right)\right](t)-\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s+1}\right)\right](t)$$

Now remember the property $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[f(s)](t)=-\dfrac{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[f'(s)\right](t)}{t}$

Derivative of $\tan ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{s-1}\right)$ is

$-\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}$ and any Laplace transform table can tell that

$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}\right](t)=-e^t \sin t$

Therefore 
$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{s-1}\right)\right](t)=-\dfrac{-e^t \sin t}{t}=\dfrac{e^t\,\sin t}{t}$

and in a similar way

$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s+1}\right)\right](t)=\dfrac{e^{-t}\, \sin (t)}{t}$

so that
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^2}\right)\right](t)=\dfrac{e^t\,\sin t}{t}-\dfrac{e^{-t}\, \sin (t)}{t}=\dfrac{\left(e^t-e^{-t}\right)\sin t}{t}=\frac{2\sinh t \sin t}{t}$$

Hope this helps

Comment: How did you get the first equality?

Comment: @AndrewFount http://www.mat.utfsm.cl/scientia/archivos/vol11/Art2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Using Inverse Laplace transform of derivatives theorem :
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\partial ^nf(s)}{\partial s^n}\right](t)=(-1)^n t^n F(t)$$

$$F(t)=\frac{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\partial ^nf(s)}{\partial s^n}\right](t)}{(-1)^n t^n}$$
in my case : $n=1$

$$-\frac{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^2}\right)\right](t)}{t}=-\frac{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{4
   s}{4+s^4}\right](t)}{t}=-\frac{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{4 s}{\left(2-2 s+s^2\right) \left(2+2
   s+s^2\right)}\right](t)}{t}=-\frac{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{1}{2-2 s+s^2}+\frac{1}{2+2
   s+s^2}\right](t)}{t}=-\frac{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{1}{((1-i)-s) ((1+i)-s)}+\frac{1}{((1-i)+s)
   ((1+i)+s)}\right](t)}{t}=-\frac{\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{i}{2 ((-1-i)+s)}-\frac{i}{2 ((-1+i)+s)}-\frac{i}{2
   ((1-i)+s)}+\frac{i}{2 ((1+i)+s)}\right](t)}{t}=-\frac{i e^{(-1-i) t} \left(-1+e^{2 i t}\right) \left(-1+e^{2 t}\right)}{2 t}=\frac{2
   \sin (t) \sinh (t)}{t}$$